# My ubuntu theme is looking weird

Tags: themes

I was using Ubuntu normally until it froze, and I had to reboot.

Then it started looking like the screen shot below.

Is there a way to go back to the original, friendly theme?

I'm using the 20.04 LTS version...

[image: Current Desktop]

It used to look like this...

[image: Previous Desktop]

Comment: `right-click, change background`

Comment: More in-depth tool, software >> Gnome Tweak tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log out, and then at the log-in screen, click on your username and before entering your password look at the corner for a cog icon, click it and pick 'Ubuntu' or try whatever options you have.

Comment: That was it!! i was using the Unity(default), changed to Ubuntu and now it's looking normal again. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your desktop was downgraded to a lower version, or the entire theme was changed to an older theme.

First check your theme settings. Go to System **Settings** > **Appearance**. You'll have a new window pop up with your desktop background and a few other settings. Make sure the **Theme** setting is the default setting, such as **Ambience**.

If you're unable to go back to the default theme settings, and cannot get the desktop configured correctly, you can reinstall the desktop environment without affecting your personal files or applications as a last resort.

You can reinstall the Ubuntu desktop environment with the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This may take several minutes, let the terminal run until it's done uninterrupted.

Comment: I've removed the Unity reinstall line. I forgot Ubuntu no longer uses Unity. However, reinstalling ubuntu-desktop could be a possible solution if they are unable to configure the settings back to the theme/desktop they had before.

Comment: The Hasan Ali answer solved my problem, but thank you guys for trying to help! <3

Comment: Reinstall of the DE could possibly help. If all other solutions fail, it could be used as a "last resort".

Comment: But the main point is this has nothing to do with "desktop was downgraded to a lower version". This "answer" fails to understand the differences between the modified Gnome Desktop that has been the standard since many years and many releases ago and the old Unity that is still available for installation.

Comment: I apologize for not making it more clear, I meant the reinstallation of the desktop as a last resort if nothing else was found useful or as a solution. I'm glad OP found a solution to their problem.